# dplyr rename_ produces error

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to rename columns using `dplyr::rename_` without success:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)

iris %>% rename("abc" = Species) # works fine

iris %>% rename_(interp(~("abc" = x), x = as.name("Species")))
```

> Error: All arguments to `rename()` must be named.

Comment: You can use the `.dots` argument, for example: `rename_(iris, .dots = c(abc = "Species"))`

Comment: Great! If you submit as answer I will accept.